# Android pool data sending using a service

Tags: android, background-process

I have an app which will send 100 data to a web api. right now I am using a service which will run through a scheduler. My problem is that scheduler is starting again before the data sending completes. How can I pause my scheduler till my process completes.

```
 public class PollReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 private static final int PERIOD=100000;
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i)
  {
scheduleAlarms(ctxt);
  }
  static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt)
   {
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, ScheduledService.class);
     PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, 0);
     mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +     PERIOD, PERIOD, pi);
   }
     }
```

Schedule Reciever

```
    public ScheduledService()
    {
    super("ScheduledService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
     {
    if (isOnline())
            {
        //Process Starts 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not plan all schedules ahead of time. Re-schedule every time a session completes/fails.

Comment: Instead of `setRepeating()` , just use `set()`, every time the service finishes its work.

Comment: I am not able to do that can you answer to my question please

Comment: Now I can only send one data out of hundred. everytime I have to start the service to send another data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a new schedule **after** sending completes. After first scedule is set, the next schedule is set by the service itself:

```
public class PollReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int PERIOD=100000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i)
    {
            scheduleNextAlarm(ctxt);
    }

    static void scheduleNextAlarm(Context c)
    {
        AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(c, ScheduledService.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(c, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + PERIOD, pi);
    }

    public static class ScheduledService extends IntentService{

        public ScheduledService() {
            super("scheduled_service");
        }


        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            try{
            // do your work
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                scheduleNextAlarm(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So one doubt I have is that I am starting the process from my main Activity.If I open the main activity the service will start from that activity also am I right.?

Comment: Having the same problem Its entering the finally block before finishing the process

Answer (score 0):

Comrade, from your code I don't see how you perform this one hudnread request, it shows only one request per some period.

What I can suggest is to to invoke your `service` per period and into the `service` use a queue for your opperation. When you call `service` you invoke the same instance of it so invoke it before pevious tasks will be completed should not be a problem.

By the way a few remarks:

- `service` does not create a thread so to avoid `ANR` exception you
  must create threads by yourself
- `IntenService` creates thread and
  moreover `IntentSrevice` handle intents one by one in the queue -- it
  seems what you need
- you can implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`
  for classes which wraps execution to the API and pass it in `intent`
  or store on the disk

Comment: could you please show me an example. It would be great if you can

Comment: Yes, I can but please extend your question -- I don't understand what you want to achieve, how are you pass the data (which requests should be executed by some period in the service)

Comment: I am retrieving the data from my sqlite database and sending to a my server.The need for scheduler is some times I would have 10 data some times I would have 100 data So basically the problem is that the service is getting started while I am waiting for the call back from the server. Thats why I want to pause the scheduler till I completes my synch.NB: After the synch I will delete the data from my local db

Comment: For this task approach offered by S.D. wil work perfectly well. It doesn't block UI because IntentService will do it's work in the another thread.